# without ssh key setup, can have write a non-interactive script to rsync/scp/etc withut me having to input the password everytime?

Tags: ssh, rsync

Is there some switch/option for `ssh` or `rsync` (something like `-u username -p passowrd`)  that would allow me to pass in the password?

Answer (score 2):

Install sshpass (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/)

then you can just do it as follows:

```
sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@ssh.yourdomain.ca
```